# How not to show view from BaseAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout, baseadapter

I have a MultiAutoCompleteTextView on which i have set a custom Adapter. Now this adapter will show a list of options for user to choose from as and when user enters some text.

This works fine in Portrait mode. However in landscape i don't want this adapter to show any view (the list of options). I don't want to remove the adapter.

I have tried setting the View to GONE.And tried to set the count to 0 so that it will not show the view at all, but due to this the data itself is gone which should not happen.

How can I make the adapter load the data but stop showing the view in landscape mode ?

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit the ArrayAdapter like this.

```
public class MyArrayAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> {

    public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if(isLandscapeMode())
            return 0;
        return super.getCount();
    }

    public boolean isLandscapeMode()
    {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        return metrics.xdpi > metrics.ydpi;
    }

}
```